# How to make code run after a tkinter window pop up

Tags: python, tkinter

My code should create a window and then count from 1 to 10 but, it
makes a window and only counts from 1 to 10 when you close the window. how do I make it count when the window pops up, not when it closes?

```
from tkinter import Tk, mainloop
import time
I = 1
window = Tk()
window.title("Game")
window.configure(width=500, height=300)
window.configure(bg='blue')
window.geometry("+" + str(I * 5) + "+0")
window.mainloop()
while I < 10:
    print(I)
    print("Hi")
    I += 1
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Just move the count code right before the window creation?

Comment: @comodoro the goal is to first make the window pop up then start the counting code but the window pops up then the code stops until I close the newly made window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop in your code only runs **after** the `window.mainloop()` (after it has ended).

This code seems to work:

```
from tkinter import Tk
I = 1
window = Tk()
window.title("Game")
window.configure(width=500, height=300)
window.configure(bg='blue')
window.geometry("+" + str(I * 5) + "+0")
def loop():
    global I
    print(I)
    print("Hi")
    I += 1
    window.after(200, loop)
loop()
window.mainloop()
```

The `window.after()` method is used to run some kind of loops even when the mainloop is running.

Answer (score 0):

What `mainloop` does is start using the main thread for GUI events and nothing else; that's why your counting code starts only after closing the window. If you want to execute code while the GUI is running, you can use the `after` method:

```
from tkinter import Tk, mainloop
import time

I = 1
# Wrap the code in a standalone method
def count():
    # In order to access a global variable from a method
    global I
    while I < 10:
        print(I)
        print("Hi")
        I += 1
        time.sleep(0.2)

window = Tk()
window.title("Game")
window.configure(width=500, height=300)
window.configure(bg='blue')
window.geometry("+" + str(I * 5) + "+0")
# In order to have the window rendered already
window.update()
# Execute code on the main thread
window.after(0, count)
window.mainloop()
```